# Unable to pin down a bug in a simple multithreading program

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I am working on a project that involves multi-threading. Although I have a decent understanding of multi-threading, I have not written many such codes. The following code is just a simple code that I wrote for hands-on. It works fine when compiled with gcc -pthread.

To build upon this code, I need to include some libraries that already have pthread included and linked. If I compile by including and linking those libraries, 3 out of 5 times it gives segmentation fault. There is some problem with the first *for*-loop in main() -- replacing this *for*-loop with multiple statements does the work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 3

pthread_mutex_t m_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char ip[20];
} thread_data;

void *doOperation(void* ctx)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_lock);
    thread_data *m_ctx = (thread_data *)ctx;
    printf("Reached here\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    thread_data ctx[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        char ip_n[] = "127.0.0.";
        char ip_h[4];
        sprintf(ip_h, "%d", i+1);
        strcpy(ctx[i].ip, strcat(ip_n, ip_h));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, doOperation, (void *)&ctx[i]) 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: `strcat(ip_n, ip_h)` - invokes *undefined behavior* unless `ip_h` has no content.

Comment: But ip_h does have content -- the string version of (i+1). I mean "1" if i is 0.

Comment: @SonuMishra, yes, that's the problem.

Comment: In general, when debugging segmentation faults (and bugs in general) a debugger is extremely helpful. Have a look at gdb - there's plenty of tutorials around: https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb%20tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the code you present "works fine", but it is buggy.  In particular, the first `for` loop is buggy, so it is not surprising that it gives you trouble under some circumstances.  Here's a breakdown:

```
    char ip_n[] = "127.0.0.";
```

You have declared `ip_n` as an array of `char` exactly long enough to hold the given initializer, including its terminating null character.

```
    char ip_h[4];
    sprintf(ip_h, "%d", i+1);
```

Supposing that the `sprintf()` succeeds, you have written a non-empty string into `char` array `ip_h`.

```
    strcpy(ctx[i].ip, strcat(ip_n, ip_h));
```

You attempt via `strcat()` to append the contents of `ip_h` to the end of `ip_n`, but there is no room -- this writes past the bounds of `ip_n`, producing undefined behavior.

The easiest way to solve this would probably be to declare `ip_n` with an explicit length that is sufficient for the full data.  In general, a dotted-quad IP address string might require as many as 16 bytes, including the terminator:

```
    char ip_n[16] = "127.0.0.";
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added `;` at the end of `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, doOperation, (void *)&ctx[i])`

And this segmentation fault might be because of

`char ip_n[] = "127.0.0.";`

Above, the `sizeof(ip_n)` only returns `9`. But you need atleast `10` characters to store string like `127.0.0.3` (Including null character at the end). Unauthorized memory access might result in segmentation fault. Try replacing this with `char ip_n[10] = "127.0.0.";`

Comment: That was just a typo when I was writing the question here. Do you find any problem with the first for loop though? As I mentioned in my question, the code does work fine when compiled explicitly with pthread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `strcat(ip_n, ip_h)` because the array `ip_n` is only big enough to hold the string `"127.0.0."`. Here's what the man page says, emphasis added

> The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the
>   null-terminated  string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string
>   s1, then add a terminating `\0'.  **The string s1 must have sufficient
>   space to hold the  result.**

The declaration should be

```
char ip_n[20] = "127.0.0.";
```

Answer (score 0):

ip_n[] points to a constant; the compiler reserved 9 bytes including the NULL byte. Anything after these 9 bytes should not be accessed and if you do, the result is undefined (it could work some of the time but likely not all the time). When you do:

```
strcat(ip_n, ip_h)
```

You are overflowing the buffer pointed to by ip_n. Maybe this is what is causing your problem. If it's not, I still recommend fixing this.

Comment: Yes, he is overflowing `ip_n`.  No, `ip_n` does not point to a constant.  It does not point to anything, in fact, because it is an array, not a pointer.  The string literal in the declaration of `ip_n` is an *initializer*.

Comment: An array variable in C contains the address of its first element. It is a constant pointer and you cannot change it after it is declared. Furthermore, your array variable points to a constant string litteral. You can do the following: p[0] or *p, which will give you the first element as in printf("%c", *ip_n);. If you want the second element, you could do printf("%c", *(ip_n + 1)); I refer you to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays under the heading "Pointers and Arrays" Cheers :-)

Comment: An array is not a pointer, period.  To the extent that the wikibook suggests differently, it is oversimplifying.  In most contexts, when an array appears in an expression, it *decays* to a pointer to its first element, but this is far different from it *being* a pointer to the first element.  There is a variety of ways by which you can distinguish, significant among them being the `sizeof` operator.